# How do i clear textviews/edittexts from one activity in another activity?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, nullreferenceexception

I'm pretty new to developing in Xamarin and I have 'some' background with WinForms using C# and Android Studio using Java.

The case is this, I already have my app 99% done. The app consists of two activities. In **Activity1** the user fills some fields with text that's needed to be sent to **Activity2** so the user can add extra data by filling out more text fields and once that's done and everything is sent to a Database Table the Activity2 executes Finish(); and then makes the user return to Activity1, which i've already done.

Now, what i want is so that when the Activity2 closes and the user is sent back to **Activity1**, i want all textfields in **ACtivity1** to be cleared out but only when everything in the **Activity2** is done because i don't want to set NoHistory to true for the Activity1 in case the user needs to go back and correct something.

I've tried creating a method either in **Activity1** that set those text fields to null, and it works by setting up a button in that same activity. I've also tried to call it in **Activity2** with:

**Activity1 activity1 = new Activity1**
**activity.method();**

Or by setting the textviews/edittexts in **Activity2** like I do in **Activity1**:

**setting a {get; set;}**
**calling the textview with a FindViewbyId**
**And then: textview.text = "" (or = null)**

I always get: **Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object**. For both options when the app tries to clear or set the textfields to null in **Activity1** when it is executed in **Activity2**.

Can someone explain to me how to just clear all textviews from one activity in another activity?

Beforehand, thank you very much for taking your time to read/help this poor soul.

Comment: Provide your code, please. Or read about nullreferenceexception https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Any chance you could please [edit] your question to include code that reproduces the problem -- i.e., a [mcve]?  Absent that we can only guess what your problem might be.  See [ask].

Comment: You have `xamarin.forms` tag, but you discuss `Activity`, which is `Xamarin.Android`. Is this app Android only? If it does NOT use any `Xamarin.Forms` UI classes, then please edit question, REMOVE `xamarin.forms` tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Activity2` needs to provide information that `Activity1` uses to decide whether to clear fields.

The principle is to **DEFER MAKING CHANGES IN Activity1** until Activity1 is the visible activity. That is, AFTER returning to Activity1.

---

Given lack of code in your question, here is one simple approach. It might not be the best approach in your situation, but it hopefully gives you some guidance.

IF `Activity2` is a "singleton" - there are never "two different Activity2s at the same time", THEN it is valid to use a **static** member of `Activity2`:

```cs
class Activity1 : Activity
{
  protected void SomeMethodThatExecutesWhenActivityBecomesVisible()
  {
    if (Activity2.IsComplete)
    {
      .. // clear text fields
    }
  }
}

class Activity2 : Activity
{
  // IMPORTANT: "static".
  public static bool IsComplete;

  protected void SomeMethodThatExecutesWhenActivityBecomesVisible()
  {
    // Because `IsComplete` is static, be sure to clear it
    // each time Activity2 is used.
    IsComplete = false;
  }

  private void MyFinishMethod()
  {
    ... // logic that decides whether user "is done with Activity2" ...
    IsComplete = ... true or false as appropriate ...;
}
```

(I haven't worked with Xamarin.Android code in a while; put in the appropriate method name for `SomeMethodThatExecutesWhenActivityBecomesVisible`.)